# Want to open hangout on air in PHP webpage using getHangoutUrl()

Tags: javascript, php, hangouts-api

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>

</script>
</script>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div33', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'hangout_type': 'onair',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '213669622632', 'start_data' : 'cwezOHm6TIQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175
  });
</script>
<div class="g-hangout" id="placeholder-div33" data-render="createhangout"></div>
```

i want to open the same using using button but on the same page below the button

Comment: More context and rephrase please :)

Comment: Please add some details...

Comment: this code working fine to run hangout on air but it will open in a new window .

Comment: I want to embed this in the same webpage where the button is.